# Can I setup a series recording based on a search in Windows Media Center?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, recording

I have Windows 7 Media Center with a OTA tuner card.

I want to record any MLB Baseball that is in the TV guide.

All I can seem to do is schedule a recording of a single game at a time.

Is there a way to setup a record series in WMC to auto-record all games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

From the main menu, go into **Recorded TV**, press up to get to **Add recording**, select it and then select the option **Create a custom recording with: wish list or keyword**.

You can set up a search based on a number of items including actor, program title, movie title and generic keyword. For MLB Baseball, I would suggest giving **Program title** a go.

Answer (score 0):

The following thread may pertain to your problem :
[Window Media Center - Guide doesn't show MLB Baseball as a series like it does in Vista](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-tv/window-media-center-guide-doesnt-show-mlb-baseball/d3d30f89-82c4-4970-883e-8e94b87e9b30).

According to the participants in the thread, this is a bug in Window Media Center
that was introduced by SP1 of Windows 7. This bug breaks series recording in general,
not only MLB Baseball.

Unfortunately, the only real solution mentioned in the thread is to convert back to Vista.
Apart from this, unless someone comes up with a solution, the only action I can think of
is to add your feedback on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) and wait for a fix, keeping your system
up to date with Windows Update.

Otherwise you could use an alternative to Window Media Center, although I have no experience
with such products and do not know how good they are at recording a series.
See these links :

[List of Window Media Center alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/windows-media-center/)
[MythTV vs. Freevo vs. XBMC vs. Mediaportal vs. Elisa vs. Boxee vs. Entertainer](http://www.vanutsteen.nl/2008/11/19/mythtv-vs-freevo-vs-xbmc-vs-mediaportal-vs-elisa/)